# How to search in Wikidata in specific categories?

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I am currently searching in Wikidata with the following query:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&language=da&limit=20&format=json&search=jordb%C3%A6r&uselang=da
```

I need to find different ingredients and food stuff.

So the query is searching for strawberries in Danish. My problem is that I get results like paintings and persons. Is there anyway to search in specific categories like food? or somehow limit the "noise" of "false" hits?

I tried to look at Wikidata and search on Google but its not clear to me what options I have.

Comment: You could check the `instance of` property (`P31`) of the results, to see if they belong to the same category

Comment: Hi @leo sorry for the late response. The content does not match `P31`, nor does it seem they all have the `instance of` either. I have come to the conclusion that it is simply not possible with food/ingredients sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/) to do this.

To find all the food in Danish, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?food ?label WHERE {
   ?food (wdt:P31?/wdt:P279*) wd:Q2095.
   ?food rdfs:label ?label.
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "da". }
   FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "da")
} ORDER BY ?label
```

[query link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Ffruit%20%3Flabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Ffood%20%28wdt%3AP31%3F%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%29%20wd%3AQ2095.%0A%20%20%3Ffood%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22da%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%29%20%3D%20%22da%22%29%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Flabel)

Or, to get all the food items labeled 'Jordbær' in Danish, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?food ?foodLabel WHERE {
  ?food (wdt:P31?/wdt:P279*) wd:Q2095 ;
        rdfs:label "Jordbær"@da;
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "da". }
}
```

[query link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Ffood%20%3FfoodLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Ffood%20%28wdt%3AP31%3F%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%29%20wd%3AQ2095%20%3B%0A%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Jordb%C3%A6r%22%40da%3B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22da%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is, at the moment, no easy way to get this kind of tailored search result, but having this same need (for books in [our case](http://github.com/inventaire/inventaire)), we ended up with 2 work-arounds:

**1 - search and filter**

- [make a general search](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&language=da&limit=20&format=json&search=jordb%C3%A6r&uselang=da)
- collect the Qids: here `Q13158`, `Q14458220`, `Q12320330`, etc
- [fetch their claims](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&ids=Q13158|Q14458220|Q12320330|Q745|Q329046|Q430057|Q1144584|Q158153|Q254669|Q990035|Q1348982|Q12320332|Q32180387|Q31246562|Q32180402|Q32180419|Q32180434|Q32180448|Q31069400|Q32180463)
- [parse the result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31290824/3324977) to get each entity's list of `P31` values
- filter the claims to keep only entities with a `P31` value of the desired domain. For instance, to keep only books, we keep entities that have a claim `P31` → `Q571` or [what we consider being aliases of Q571](https://github.com/inventaire/inventaire/blob/c3b71d1d523e07267fceb98d962150999b72ecb9/server/lib/wikidata/aliases.coffee#L18-L34). This list is static because books are "rather" consistent in their P31 values, but for your domain, you would probably need to generate that list dynamically from [a SPARQL query to get a complete list of things that are considered subclasses of food or ingredients](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ2095%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ10675206%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22da%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0A).

**2 - filter and search**

- make the SPARQL request that get's all the valid results (see [query.wikidata.org documentation](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/Wikidata_Query_Help)), once for all (but needs to be updated periodically)
- put all those results in your own search engine. See our [Wikidata Subset Search Engine](https://github.com/inventaire/wikidata-subset-search-engine) project
- then, when needed, make your request to that search engine instead