# How to get all property from an item based on its Q number?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to gather all properties of a item from wikidata.

All queries I see so far assume you know properties you are looking for, but in my case, I'm not.

For example, when querying for [Q1798740](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ1798740%29%7D%20%0A%7D%0A), I would like a returned value that looks like

```
[{"item": "Q1798740",
  "P31": ["Q1146"],
  "P17": ["Q70972"],
  ...
  "P2043":"70 metres"}
]
```

and that contains all statements from the [wikidata page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1798740)

What query should I perform?

Comment: no need to use SPARQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906932/how-to-programmatically-get-all-available-information-from-a-wikidata-entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only to ask for `{wd:Q1798740 ?p ?value}` but it would be useful also to get the labels of the properties, which is a bit trickier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p ?property_label ?value 
WHERE
{
wd:Q1798740 ?p ?value .

?property wikibase:directClaim ?p ;
          rdfs:label ?property_label .

 FILTER(LANG(?property_label)="en")
}
```

Comment: a more complete solution was already given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383784/wikidata-get-all-properties-with-labels-and-values-of-an-item