# Extract data from Wikidata in Python

Tags: python, json, wikidata-api

With the following code it is possible to extract data from entities in Wikidata:

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php"

query = "wikipedia"

params = {
    'action': 'wbsearchentities',
    'format': 'json',
    'language': 'en',
    'search': query
}

r = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params = params)

print(r.json()['search'][0])
```

and the output is:

```
{'repository': '', 'id': 'Q52', 'concepturi': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q52', 'title': 'Q52', 'pageid': 170, 'url': '//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q52', 'label': 'Wikipedia', 'description': 'free online encyclopedia that anyone can edit', 'match': {'type': 'label', 'language': 'en', 'text': 'Wikipedia'}}
```

But going to the **concepturi** 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q52 I see more information than reported here in the json file, specifically I am interested on ***motto text*** field.

How could I get more information from Wikidata? (this is an example more could be shown where the query outputs less info than contained in Wikidata).

Comment: This question is not programming related, it is about the Wikidata API. I suggest you read [the documentation](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access).

Comment: Use the `wbgetentities` URL: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q52&format=json

Comment: Thanks @intentionally left blank, Im a little bit lost, I am reading the api documentation, hoping see something clear enough.

Comment: In SPARQL: http://paws-public.wmflabs.org/paws-public/User:Luitzen/Motto.ipynb

Comment: Please, see [Getting readable results from Wikidata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266398/getting-readable-results-from-wikidata/31290824).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use wikidata python module [**qwikidata**](https://qwikidata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html)

```
from qwikidata.sparql  import return_sparql_query_results

query_string = """
        SELECT $WDid
         WHERE {
          ?WDid (wdt:P279)* wd:Q4022
        }"""

res = return_sparql_query_results(query_string)

for row in res["results"]["bindings"]:
   print(row["yourFieldName"]["value"])
```

Comment: There seems to be an even more mature python package called [wikidata](https://github.com/dahlia/wikidata).